# can not access the folders created in cpanel

Tags: php, linux, cpanel

why for the directories i creat getting `rwx---rwx`and `rw----r--` permisions for the files i create?
I cant access a folder by externally via url which have rwx---rwx permition but can access the file which have rw----r-- permision.

Even I change permision to `rwxrwxrwx` i can not access the folder.
eg:
http://www.example.com/folder/
Gives me 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

403 forbidden on a folder url usually means that your server has folder browsing disabled, and there's no default document (index.html, index.php, etc...) in the directory. Since there's no default content to server, and the configuration doesn't allow for browsing, you get the forbidden error.

Comment: there is index.html inside htdocs..im guessing its the hosting providers server configaration. what a useless configaration know. thanks for your answer by the way. :)

Comment: Yes, but there has to be an index.html in EVERY directory you create. e.g. If you're trying to access `example.com/blah`, then there has to be a default doc in that blah directory. Having a default document at the top of the docroot (`example.com`) has no effect on sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably a pre-caution of your webserver, that denies to offer files that have the executable bit (`x`) set.

Check your servers documentation about the features it offers and which file permissions are needed to be set to make them work with your webserver.